# Get date for Monday and Friday for the current week

Tags: php, date, datetime

How can I get the date for Monday and Friday for the current week?

I have the following code, but it fails if current day is Sunday or Saturday.

```
$current_day = date("N");
$days_to_friday = 5 - $current_day;
$days_from_monday = $current_day - 1;
$monday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("- {$days_from_monday} Days"));
$friday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ {$days_to_friday} Days"));
```

Comment: Are you counting Sunday as the start or the end of the week?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Assuming your week starts on Monday you can use `DateTime` class with specific [relative formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

To get the Monday and Friday for the current week:

```
$mondayThisWeek = new DateTimeImmutable("monday this week");
$fridayThisWeek = new DateTimeImmutable("friday this week");

// so when current date is Sun, 07 Jan 2024
// $mondayThisWeek will be Mon, 01 Jan 2024
// $fridayThisWeek will be Fri, 05 Jan 2024
```

To get Monday and Friday relative to a specific date:

```
$referenceDate = new DateTimeImmutable("2024-01-07");
$thatMonday = $referenceDate->modify("monday this week");
$thatFriday = $referenceDate->modify("friday this week");

// $thatMonday will be Mon, 01 Jan 2024
// $thatFriday will be Fri, 05 Jan 2024
```

---

If your week starts on (for example) Sunday then you will have to calculate Monday and Friday manually. Here is an example:

```
$referenceDate = new DateTimeImmutable("2024-01-07");
$dayOfWeek = (int) $referenceDate->format("w");
// 0 = Sun
// 1 = Mon
// 2 = Tue
// 3 = Wed
// 4 = Thu
// 5 = Fri
// 6 = Sat

if ($dayOfWeek === 0) {
    $mondayModifier = "next monday";
} elseif ($dayOfWeek === 1) {
    $mondayModifier = "today";
} else {
    $mondayModifier = "previous monday";
}

if ($dayOfWeek < 5) {
    $fridayModifier = "next friday";
} elseif ($dayOfWeek === 5) {
    $fridayModifier = "today";
} else {
    $fridayModifier = "previous friday";
}

$thatMonday = $referenceDate->modify($mondayModifier);
$thatFriday = $referenceDate->modify($fridayModifier);

// $thatMonday will be Mon, 08 Jan 2024
// $thatFriday will be Fri, 12 Jan 2024
```

Comment: nice Ans but what is i want to get monday from date . as 01-01-2012 will return 2-01-2012

Comment: @chhameed: `strtotime("next monday", strtotime("2012-01-01"))`. Second parameter, if specified, is used as reference date.

Comment: What happens if it's currently `Monday` and we call `strtotime( "previous monday")` ?

Comment: @kelly the user is supposed to check today's day-of-week and use prev OR next monday depending on the result. When I posted this answer, strtotime's week handling was horribly broken. Also AFAIK, PHP does not let you specify first day of week... and nobody knew what PHP considered start of week.

Comment: @SalmanA I could see that. Php is a pretty volatile language.

Answer (score 93):

Best solution would be:

```
$monday = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'monday this week' ) );
$friday = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'friday this week' ) );
```

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer. There is no difference between "this friday" and "next friday". You have to use "friday this week" and "friday next week"

Comment: Thanks. 'this week' - is exactly what I searched in such question.

Comment: What does "this week" mean? A week starting on monday or week starting sunday? You cannot tell because it depends on PHP version. See https://3v4l.org/v1ZI7 **and click EOL versions**. Some 7.x versions produce unexpected results.

Answer (score 11):

This question needs a DateTime answer:-

```
/**
 * @param String $day
 * @return DateTime
 */
function getDay($day)
{
    $days = ['Monday' => 1, 'Tuesday' => 2, 'Wednesday' => 3, 'Thursday' => 4, 'Friday' => 5, 'Saturday' => 6, 'Sunday' => 7];

    $today = new \DateTime();
    $today->setISODate((int)$today->format('o'), (int)$today->format('W'), $days[ucfirst($day)]);
    return $today;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var_dump(getDay('Monday')->format('l dS F Y'));
var_dump(getDay('Friday')->format('l dS F Y'));
```

**Output:**

```
string 'Monday 30th September 2013' (length=26)
string 'Friday 04th October 2013' (length=24)
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/ApLHk)

Answer (score 2):

i use :

```
$first_week_date = date('d F Y', strtotime('next Monday -1 week', strtotime('this sunday')));
$last_week_date = date('d F Y', strtotime('next Monday -1 week + 4 days', strtotime('this sunday')));
```

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on how you define **a week** but I came up with this function that will give you the date for the nearest "monday" or "friday" (or any day for that matter):

```
function closestDate($day){

    $day = ucfirst($day);
    if(date('l', time()) == $day)
        return date("Y-m-d", time());
    else if(abs(time()-strtotime('next '.$day)) < abs(time()-strtotime('last '.$day)))
        return date("Y-m-d", strtotime('next '.$day));
    else
        return date("Y-m-d", strtotime('last '.$day));

}
```

Input: a day of the week ("sunday", "Monday", etc.)

Output: If I asked for the nearest "sunday" and today is:

1. "Sunday": I will get today's date
2. "Monday": I will get yesterday's date
3. "Saturday: I will get tomorrow's date

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

As the top answer suggests, using PHP's [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function is the easiest way.

However, instead of using if statements as he suggests, you could simply reset back to the previous Sunday and grab the dates you require from there.

```
$monday = strtotime('next monday', strtotime('previous sunday'));
$friday = strtotime('next friday', strtotime('previous sunday'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a definition of the current week per ISO 8601. I want Monday to always be defined as the Monday that started this current week.

The following solution works excellent for me:

```
$monday = strtotime(date('o-\WW'));
$friday = strtotime("next friday",$monday);
```

For `$monday`, this method will always return the Monday that started this calendar week. unfortunately, this method relies on PHP 5.1 to parse the `o` date format.

To get any day of the week, you could try:

```
function time_for_week_day($day_name, $ref_time=null){
    $monday = strtotime(date('o-\WW',$ref_time));
    if(substr(strtoupper($day_name),0,3) === "MON")
        return $monday;
    else
        return strtotime("next $day_name",$monday);
}
```

Usage:

```
time_for_week_day('wednesday');
time_for_week_day('friday',strtotime('2014-12-25'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar thing, except I wanted any Monday, not just this week.  This is what I came up with:

```
function getSunday(DateTime $date){
    $outdate = clone($date);
    $day = $date->format("w");  // get the weekday (sunday is 0)
    $outdate->sub(new DateInterval("P".$day."D")); // subtracting the weekday from the date always gives Sunday 
    return $outdate;
}
```

It accepts an arbitrary date and gives the Sunday.  Then you can easily add back days to get Monday through Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

get the current week

```php
        $week = [];
        $saturday = strtotime('saturday this week');
        foreach (range(0, 6) as $day) {
            $week[] = date("Y-m-d", (($day * 86400) + $saturday));
        }
```