# how do i get the 1st day of week from current date

Tags: php, date, logic

I would like get the 1st date of week?
ie.

```
 if 2011-01-01 then 2011-01-01  
    if 2011-01-06 then 2011-01-01  
    if 2011-01-20 then 2011-01-14  
    if 2011-01-21 then 2011-01-21
```

Sorry for misleading and making question confusion.

I just want to get the date of the 1st day of the week, ie. either 1 or 7 or 14 or 21 or 28

Comment: Do you consider Monday or Sunday as your first day of the week? It will make a difference to the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get date for monday and friday for the current week (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431631/get-date-for-monday-and-friday-for-the-current-week-php)

Comment: You still haven't defined "first day of the week" properly. "1 or 7 or 14" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Weeks do not always start on 1, 7, 14, 21, 28 etc. The 1st of February was a Tuesday, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider monday as the first day of week

```
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime("last monday", strtotime('tomorrow',strtotime($date))));
```

You can replace `monday` with any day of week.

Comment: It will fail if today is monday

Comment: I'd better prefer to use "tomorrow" feature: `echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime("last monday", strtotime('tomorrow', strtotime($date))));` --- in this case you don't need to add another check.

Answer (score 2):

By far the most straight-forward way is to subtract the number of the day of the week (0 = Sunday for `'w'`, 1 = Monday for `'N'`) in days from the date:

```
$date = strtotime('2011-02-09');
$sunday = strtotime('-' . date('w', $date) . ' days', $date);
$monday = strtotime('-' . (date('N', $date) - 1) . ' days', $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$wk_day=date('w');
switch ($wk_day)
{
  case 0:  $diff = -1;        break;
  case 1:  $diff = 0;         break;
  default :$diff = $wk_day-1; break;
}
echo date('Y-m-d', time()-(86400*$diff));
```

Comment: If you consider Monday as your first day, then you should change the first line to this: `$wk_day=date('N');` and the case should start at **1** and you should then change the case accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_date =date('Y-m-d'); 

$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');
$day = date('d');

$first_day = get_week_start($year, $month, $day);

$weeks_first_day =date('Y-m-d',$first_day);


    function get_week_start($year, $month, $day)
    {
    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
    return $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, date('d', $timestamp)-date('w', $timestamp), $year);
    }
```

you can get weeks first day from $weeks_first_day, you can also change format  what ever  !

here Sunday is the start date