# How to show in php only current weekday.After passing of current week only then next weekdays show

Tags: php

I have this code.That is showing 5 business days(that is correct). but i want only current weekdays even that is passed. after passing of current week next weekdays shows

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++): ?>
    <label ><?php echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime("+$i Weekday")); ?></label>
    <label ><?php echo date('l',strtotime("+$i Weekday")); ?></label><br>   
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Its output is:
19-Nov-2014 Wednesday
20-Nov-2014 Thursday
21-Nov-2014 Friday
24-Nov-2014 Monday
25-Nov-2014 Tuesday

This is also showing next week days.
what i want is like this:
    17-Nov-2014 Monday
    18-Nov-2014 Tuesday
    19-Nov-2014 Wednesday
    20-Nov-2014 Thursday
    21-Nov-2014 Friday

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431631/get-date-for-monday-and-friday-for-the-current-week-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$monday_this_week = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('monday this week'));
<?php for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++): ?>
    <?php $date = date('d-M-Y', strtotime("+$i days", strtotime($monday_this_week))); ?>
    <label ><?php echo $date; ?></label>
    <label ><?php echo date('l', strtotime($date)); ?></label><br>   
<?php endfor; ?>
```