# How do I display the start and end date of the current week in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I wrapped around my head with this a long time, What I trying do is getting the **start** and **end** date of this current week.

This current week starts from **20th May(Monday)** to **26th May(Sunday)**

**My approach:**

```
//GETTING DATA FOR CURRENT WEEK

$dtFrom_current = new DateTime; // get current date
$dtTo_current = new DateTime;


$dtFrom_current->setISODate($dtFrom_current->format('o'), $dtFrom_current->format('W'));

$dtTo_current->setISODate($dtTo_current->format('o'), $dtTo_current->format('W') );
// add 1 day
$dtTo_current->add(new DateInterval('P1D') + 1 );

// convert to iso date for database use
echo   $dFrom_current = $dtFrom_current->format('Y-m-d');
echo  $dTo_current   = $dtTo_current->format('Y-m-d');
```

But I am dam sure I am doing something wrong, but don't know what, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get date for monday and friday for the current week (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431631/get-date-for-monday-and-friday-for-the-current-week-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably just missing a tiny detail there.

First, `DateInterval` should receive its param in an interval specification format. Refer to https://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php.
And besides, you are just adding 1 day to your interval, and you should add 6, based on what you are trying to achieve:

`$dtTo_current->add( new DateInterval( 'P6D' ) );`

Take a look at the refactored code and test it:

```
//GETTING DATA FOR CURRENT WEEK

$dtFrom_current = new DateTime; // get current date
$dtTo_current   = new DateTime;

$dtFrom_current->setISODate( $dtFrom_current->format( 'o' ), $dtFrom_current->format( 'W' ) );

$dtTo_current->setISODate( $dtTo_current->format( 'o' ), $dtTo_current->format( 'W' ) );
// add 1 day
$dtTo_current->add( new DateInterval( 'P6D' ) );

// convert to iso date for database use
echo $dFrom_current = $dtFrom_current->format( 'Y-m-d' );
echo "\n";
echo $dTo_current = $dtTo_current->format( 'Y-m-d' );
```

Comment: ah, great that what I am missing, thank you for your time and efforts its works like a charm:)